# Retrofit gives null response while calling Post request from android

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

Current response

```
Response{protocol=http/1.0, code=404, message=Not Found, 
    url=http://testapp*****/api/dev/myapp**/subscription%2F2be110}
```

But url which i'm passing is

```
url=http://testapp*****/api/dev/myapp**/subscription/2be110
```

**"subscription/2be110"** which is passing as string to api service which receives at following function

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8","Accept: application/json")
    @POST("{urlEndString}")
    fun getResponse(
        @Path ("urlEndString") urlEndString : String, @Body `object`: JsonObject
    ):Call<JsonObject>
```

How back slash changed to "%2F" format ? Any solution to resolve this issue?

*Nb: using retrofit2*

Comment: You need to url encoding of Url  @FormUrlEncoded

Comment: i've tried @FormUrlEncoded , but it doest return any response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Path` parameters are URLEncoded. Therefore slash will be URLEncoded as well. You can use 2 path parameters like

```
@POST("{urlEndString1}/{urlEndString2}")
fun getResponse(
        @Path ("urlEndString1") urlEndString1 : String, @Path ("urlEndString2") urlEndString2 : String, @Body `object`: JsonObject):Call<JsonObject>
```

And pass 2 parts of your URL ending split by slash.

As alternative, you can use `@Path(value="urlEndString", encoded=true)` to show that the parameter is already encoded, and Retrofit does not need to encode it.

Comment: thanks @Vladyslav Matviienko , it works fine, i've a doubt is there any possibility that i can pass path as array?

Comment: @SARATHV can you show an example URL you want to get?

Comment: for example, "testapp*****/api/dev/myapp**/ " - constant url, i want 4 subpaths like urlEndString1, urlEndString2, urlEndString3 ..... etc if necessary. In that case do i really need to add new post function for this ? or i could have an alternate method? Sorry if i'm not making any sense...

Comment: please show the example, it is not clear from your description

Comment: example : in case 1: url = com.example.myapp/string1  ; case 2: url = com.example.myapp/string1/string2/ ; case 3: url = com.example.myapp/string1/string2/string3 ...... is it ok? or just leave it. Anyways thanks for the time.My current prob solved and i'll figure my doubts later